# How are tkinter buttons named in lists?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am codeing a TicTacToe game at the moment and I tried to let the programm automatically detect when a player wins like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


#---------------------------------------Definitions-------------------------------------------------
def startgame():
    global whois
    whois = 1
    turn.place(x=413, y=150)
    Player1.place(x=10, y=5)
    Player2.place(x=10, y=45)
    PlayerCross.place(x=150, y=52)
    PlayerCircle.place(x=150, y=10)
    error.place(x=260, y=920)
    A1.place(x=158, y=204, width=223, height=228)
    A2.place(x=387, y=204, width=232, height=228)
    A3.place(x=626, y=204, width=225, height=228)
    B1.place(x=158, y=438, width=223, height=231)
    B2.place(x=387, y=438, width=232, height=231)
    B3.place(x=626, y=438, width=225, height=231)
    C1.place(x=158, y=675, width=223, height=226)
    C2.place(x=387, y=675, width=232, height=226)
    C3.place(x=626, y=675, width=225, height=226)
    startscreen.place_forget()
    start.place_forget()
    turn["text"] = "Player 1's turn!"
    whowon.place(x = 330, y = 330)

#----------------------------------Here is my Problem-----------------------------------------------

def turnimage(a):
    global whois
    if whois == 1 and a["image"] == str(standartTexture):
        turn["text"] = "Player 2's turn!"
        a["image"] = circle
        whois = 2
        error["text"] = ""
        Player1list.append(a)
        player1win()
    elif whois == 2 and a["image"] == str(standartTexture):
        turn["text"] = "Player 1's turn!"
        a["image"] = cross
        whois = 1
        error["text"] = ""
        Player2list.append(a)
        player1win()

    else:
        error["text"] = "This field is already occupied!"
Player1list = []
Player2list = []
def player1win():
    if "A1" in Player1list and "A2" in Player1list and "A3" in Player1list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 1 won"
    if "B1" in Player1list and "B2" in Player1list and "B3" in Player1list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 1 won"
    if "C1" in Player1list and "C2" in Player1list and "C3" in Player1list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 1 won"
    if "A1" in Player1list and "B1" in Player1list and "C1" in Player1list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 1 won"
    if "A2" in Player1list and "B2" in Player1list and "C2" in Player1list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 1 won"
    if "A3" in Player1list and "B3" in Player1list and "C3" in Player1list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 1 won"
    if "A1" in Player1list and "B2" in Player1list and "C3" in Player1list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 1 won"
    if "A§" in Player1list and "B2" in Player1list and "C1" in Player1list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 1 won"

def player2win():
    if "A1" in Player1list and "A2" in Player1list and "A3" in Player2list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 2 won"
    if "B1" in Player1list and "B2" in Player1list and "B3" in Player2list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 2 won"
    if "C1" in Player1list and "C2" in Player1list and "C3" in Player2list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 2 won"
    if "A1" in Player1list and "B1" in Player1list and "C1" in Player2list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 2 won"
    if "A2" in Player1list and "B2" in Player1list and "C2" in Player2list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 2 won"
    if "A3" in Player1list and "B3" in Player1list and "C3" in Player2list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 2 won"
    if "A1" in Player1list and "B2" in Player1list and "C3" in Player2list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 2 won"
    if "A§" in Player1list and "B2" in Player1list and "C1" in Player2list:
        whowon["text"] = "Player 2 won"

#---------------------------------------------variables-------------------------------------------------------

backgroundpicture = tk.PhotoImage(file = "TicTacToe_bg.png")
standartTexture = tk.PhotoImage(file = "standartTexture.png")
cross = tk.PhotoImage(file = "cross.png")
circle = tk.PhotoImage(file = "circle.png")
PlayerCrossImage = tk.PhotoImage(file = "PlayerCross.png")
PlayerCircleImage = tk.PhotoImage(file = "PlayerCircle.png")



whois = 0
field = tk.Label(root, image = backgroundpicture)
turn = tk.Label(root, text = " ", bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#000000", font = "Ariel 20")
Player1 = tk.Label(root, text = "Player 1 = ", bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#000000", font = "Ariel 20")
Player2 = tk.Label(root, text = "Player 2 = ", bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#000000", font = "Ariel 20")
PlayerCross = tk.Label(root, image = PlayerCrossImage, bd = 0)
PlayerCircle = tk.Label(root, image = PlayerCircleImage, bd = 0)
startscreen = tk.Label(root, text = "", height = 500, width = 500, bg = "#FFFFFF")
start = tk.Button(root, text = "Start", font = "Ariel 50", bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#000000", command = startgame)
error = tk.Label(root, text = "", font = "Ariel 30", bg = "#FFFFFF")

A1 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(A1))
A2 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(A2))
A3 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(A3))
B1 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(B1))
B2 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(B2))
B3 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(B3))
C1 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(C1))
C2 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(C2))
C3 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(C3))

whowon = tk.Label(root, text = "", font = "Ariel 20", bg = "#FFFFFF")
#--------------------------------------------place stuff-----------------------------------------------------------------

startscreen.place(x = 148, y = 195)
field.pack()
start.place(x = 400, y = 400)

root.mainloop()
```

But this doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?
I also tried to let me print the lists first and the buttons weren't named A1 A2 and so on but i coudn't figure out how i have to name them.

Comment: If `A1` (for example) is the object that was added to the list, then `A1` is the object that you should check for being in the list.  Not `"A1"` (that's a string, and there are no strings in the list), check for the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use *smart data* instead of code.

First, put your buttons in a list;

```
buttons = [A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3]
```

Next you should have a nested tuple of winning combinations. These combinations are indexes into the buttons list.

```
winners = (
   (0,1,2),
   (3,4,5),
   (6,7,8),
   ...
)
```

And you could replaces all of your code with a nested loop:

```
for comb in winners:
    for player in ('X', 'O'):
        if all(buttons[j]["text"] == player for j in comb):
            winner = True
            # Give the winning combination a color.
            for k in comb:
                buttons[k].config(bg='#EE2923')
            # Inform the user
            tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', f'User playing for "{player}" - won!')
            # Reset all buttons
            buttons_off()
            # Restart the game.
            restart()
```

Comment: OK I am a bit confused but thank you!